# PHP Array_Push not working

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I am trying to organize a set of results that obtained through a database query. Here is the code I'm using to do this:

```
$time_slots = $wpdb->get_results($query);
print_r($time_slots); 
echo ("<br/><br/><br/><br/>");
/*organize slots into array*/


$openings = array(); 
foreach($time_slots as $ts)
{
    if(empty($openings))
    {
        echo("Empty Array: ");
        echo ("<br/>");
        echo ("<br/>");
        echo("Inserting: ");
        print_r($ts); 
        echo ("<br/>");
        echo ("<br/>");
        $openings[$ts->route_date] = $ts; 
        echo("contents of Opening: ");
        echo ("<br/>");
        echo ("<br/>");
        print_r($openings); 
        echo ("<br/><br/><br/><br/>");

    }
    elseif (array_key_exists($ts->route_date, $openings)) 
    {
        echo("Same Day");
        echo ("<br/>");
        echo ("<br/>");
        echo("Inserting: ");
        print_r($ts); 
        echo ("<br/>");
        echo ("<br/>");
        array_push($openings[$ts->route_date][$ts->name], $ts); 
        echo("contents of Opening: ");
        echo ("<br/>");
        echo ("<br/>");
        print_r($openings); 
        echo ("<br/><br/><br/><br/>");
    }
    else
    {
        echo("New Day : ");
        echo ("<br/>");
        echo ("<br/>");
        echo("Inserting: ");
        print_r($ts); 
        echo ("<br/>");
        echo ("<br/>");
        $openings[$ts->route_date] = $ts; 
        echo("contents of Opening: ");
        echo ("<br/>");
        echo ("<br/>");
        print_r($openings); 
        echo ("<br/><br/><br/><br/>"); 
    }
}

/*return results*/
$result['openings'] = $openings; 
$result['time'] = $time_slots;  
$result['begin'] = $begin; 
$result['end'] = $end; 
$result['query'] = $query; 
$result['type'] = "success"; 
$result = json_encode($result);
print_r($openings);
```

Here is what a single result looks like when I `print_r` the `$ts`:

```
 stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-10 [name] => 2 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 )
```

Here is what one loop looks like. You will notice that the logic works, and that everything is going where it should go, but the adding t:

```
> Empty Array: 

Inserting: stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-10 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) 

contents of Opening: 

Array ( [2014-01-10] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-10 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) ) 



Same Day

Inserting: stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-10 [name] => 1 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) 

contents of Opening: 

Array ( [2014-01-10] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-10 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) ) 



Same Day

Inserting: stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-10 [name] => 2 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) 

contents of Opening: 

Array ( [2014-01-10] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-10 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) ) 



Same Day

Inserting: stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-10 [name] => 3 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) 

contents of Opening: 

Array ( [2014-01-10] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-10 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) ) 



Same Day

Inserting: stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-10 [name] => 4 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) 

contents of Opening: 

Array ( [2014-01-10] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-10 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) ) 



New Day : 

Inserting: stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-11 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) 

contents of Opening: 

Array ( [2014-01-10] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-10 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-01-11] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-11 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) ) 



Same Day

Inserting: stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-11 [name] => 1 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) 

contents of Opening: 

Array ( [2014-01-10] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-10 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-01-11] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-11 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) )
```

When it is all said and done, I get this result:

> Array ( [2014-01-10] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-10 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-01-11] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-11 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-01-12] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-12 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-01-13] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-13 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-01-14] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-14 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-01-15] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-15 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-01-16] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-16 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-01-17] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-17 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-01-18] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-18 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-01-19] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-19 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-01-20] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-20 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-01-21] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-21 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-01-22] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-22 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-01-23] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-23 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-01-24] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-24 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-01-25] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-25 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-01-26] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-26 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-01-27] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-27 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-01-28] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-28 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-01-29] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-29 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-01-30] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-30 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-01-31] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-01-31 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-01] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-01 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-02] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-02 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-03] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-03 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-04] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-04 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-05] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-05 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-06] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-06 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-07] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-07 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-08] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-08 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-09] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-09 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-10] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-10 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-11] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-11 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-12] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-12 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-13] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-13 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-14] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-14 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-15] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-15 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-16] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-16 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-17] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-17 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-18] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-18 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-19] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-19 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-20] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-20 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-21] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-21 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-22] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-22 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-23] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-23 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-24] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-24 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-25] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-25 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-26] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-26 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) [2014-02-27] => stdClass Object ( [route_date] => 2014-02-27 [name] => 0 [openings] => 1 [appointments] => 0 ) )

You will notice that only the first instance of the first object is added to the new array `$openings`.

UPDATE:

I just realized that I need a multidimensional array for this, but when I try add the second dimension, I get the following error:

```
 Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

What Am I doing wrong here? I want a single array `$openings[route_date][number]` but I can't get it work. Any help would be great.

Comment: by the way, please pretty print such arrays, by adding `echo "<pre>"` before the output and `echo "</pre>"` after it..

Comment: I didn't know you could do that! That is so awesome!!!! Thank you!!!!

Comment: you're welcome, just a tip you should be aware of.. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's because `array_push()` works with arrays, not objects. You should convert your `stdClass` to array. Try to use:

```
$ts = (array) $ts;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `array_push($openings[$ts->route_date][$ts->name], $ts);`   the first  argument doesn't seem to be an array. array_push() will raise a warning if the first argument is not an array.

```
This should be array_push($openings, $ts);
```

I've made an example which works fine.

```
//I'm using mysql and I will switch to  MySQLi or PDO_MySQL later) 

$query = "SELECT * FROM events";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$openings = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    array_push($openings, $row); 
}
print_r($openings);

//output

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [idevent] => 1
            [event] => Event1
            [event_date] => 2014-01-06
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [idevent] => 2
            [event] => Event2
            [event_date] => 2014-01-07
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to do a couple of things. Here is the code I needed:

```
    $time_slots = $wpdb->get_results($query);
echo("<pre>"); 
//print_r($time_slots); 

echo ("<br/><br/><br/><br/>");
/*organize slots into array*/


$openings = array(); 
foreach($time_slots as $ts)
{
    if(empty($openings))
    {
        echo("Empty Array: ");
        echo ("<br/>");

        echo("Inserting: ");
        echo ("<pre>");
        print_r($ts); 
        echo("</pre>");
        echo ("<pre>");
        $openings[$ts->route_date][$ts->name] = $ts; <--- Needed to add the [$ts->name]
        echo("</pre>");
        echo("contents of Opening: ");
        echo ("<pre>");
        print_r($openings); 
        echo ("</pre>");

    }
    elseif (array_key_exists($ts->route_date, $openings)) 
    {
        echo("Same Day");
        echo("Inserting: ");
        echo ("<pre>");
        print_r($ts); 
        echo("</pre>");
        $openings[$ts->route_date][$ts->name]=$ts; 
        echo("contents of Opening: ");
        echo ("<br/>");
        echo ("<br/>");
        print_r($openings); 
        echo ("<br/><br/><br/><br/>");
    }
    else
    {
        echo("New Day : ");
        echo("Inserting: ");
        echo ("<pre>");
        print_r($ts); 
        echo("</pre>");
        echo ("<pre>");
        $openings[$ts->route_date][$ts->name] = $ts; 
        echo("</pre>");
        echo("contents of Opening: ");
        echo ("<pre>");
        print_r($openings); 
        echo ("</pre>");
    }
```